# What is the role of the ADSSYS user automatically created in an Advantage data dictionary?

Tags: permissions, advantage-database-server

When creating a data dictionary in Advantage Database Server (Sybase), the system automatically creates a user named ADSSYS. What's the role of this user, and can we remove it from our applications?

Answer (score 4):

From the Advantage help:

`All Advantage data dictionaries contain an administrative user called ADSSYS. This user has permissions to perform any operation or update on the dictionary. Be aware that if the ADSSYS password is lost, it cannot be recovered or reset`

I don't think you can remove the user, just set a secure password, it acts like an Administrator account.

You can specify any username in your application. If you connect as `ADSSYS` or an empty username the `ADSSYS` user will be used. Connection will of course fail if the given password is wrong.

Bottom line: Just set a secure password for the `ADSSYS` user.

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.0/server1/advantage_data_dictionary_user_permissions.htm

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=17&SearchKeyWords=adssys

Comment: All information is correct, but I would add that you really DON'T want to use adssys in your application.  You want to create users that have the needed level of access and then use those.  ADSSYS lets you do anything, similar to root in Linux.  You wouldn't use root in an application; you shouldn't use ADSSYS.  You can create another administrative account that has all of the needed permissions for adding, granting, etc.  One problem using ADSSYS, if you create a table for temporary use logged in as ADSSYS, it gets added to the data dictionary automatically, which you probably done't want.